# python memory leak

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, pygame

I have an array of 'cell' objects created like so:

```
class Cell:
  def __init__(self, index, type, color):
    self.index = index
    self.type = type
    self.score = 0
    self.x = index%grid_size
    self.y = int(index/grid_size)
    self.color = colour


alpha = 0.8
b = 2.0
grid_size = 100
scale = 5

number_cells = grid_size*grid_size
num_cooperators = int(number_cells*alpha)       
cells = range(number_cells)
random.shuffle(cells)
cooperators = cells[0:num_cooperators]
defectors = cells[num_cooperators:number_cells]
cells = [Cell(i, 'C', blue) for i in cooperators]
cells += [Cell(i, 'D', red) for i in defectors]
cells.sort(compare)
```

I am grabbing attributes from them in a loop like so:

```
while 1:
    pixArr = pygame.PixelArray(windowSurfaceObj)
    for cell in cells:
        x = cell.x
        y = cell.y
        color = cell.color
        for y_offset in range(0,scale):
            for x_offset in range(0,scale):
                pixArr[x*scale + x_offset][y*scale + y_offset] = color
    del pixArr
    pygame.display.update()
```

I am leaking memory like crazy... what's going on?

Comment: How have you determined that you are leaking memory?

Comment: I noticed when the music playing on my machine started skipping, so I looked at my system activity.  It starts at somewhere around 100MB of memory usage but very quickly gets up to a GB or 2!

Comment: And what about `number_cells` and `num_cooperators`?

Comment: I'm guessing the loop you show is inside another loop for generations. Are you storing the `pixArr` for each generation?

Comment: please see updated post with more detail

Comment: the leak itself occurs during the line pixArr[x*scale...

Comment: and it appears to occur purely due to the arithmetic in the brackets.  I will check out what is going on there and hopefully get to the bottom of it!

Comment: I doubt you really are leaking memory. Leaking is when memory is allocated but then never deallocated. Since you operate inside the Python machine, I'm pretty sure you won't be leaking .

What's probably happening is that you are allocating a lot of memory and then the garbage collector is deciding not to return it to the system immediately. That is its prerogative.

Comment: Why are you updating the display in a tight loop like that? I think you need to put in some kind of delay or only update when your data in cells actually changes.

Comment: OP, did you ever solve the problem? I'm  having the same issue now.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug in PixelArray.

The following code replicates the memory leak by setting a single pixel each loop, and you don't even have to update the display to cause the problem:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight = 640, 480
pygame.init()
Display = pygame.display.set_mode((ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Memory Leak Test')
while True:
    PixelArray = pygame.PixelArray(Display)
    PixelArray[ScreenWidth-1][ScreenHeight-1] = (255,255,255)
    del PixelArray
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
#pygame.display.update()
```

If you can handle the performance hit, replacing direct pixel setting with (very short) lines avoids the memory leak, ie: pygame.draw.line(Display, Colour, (X,Y), (X,Y), 1)

Comment: I'm on Python 3.4.0 and using PyGame 1.9.2a0, and running this doesn't give me the leak.

Answer (score 0):

The *Cell* class can be tighted-up (memorysize) by using slots.  That ought to substantially reduce memory consumption:

```
class Cell(object):
    __slots__ = ('index', 'type', 'color')
    ...
```

The only large structure in your code is pixArr.  You might want to monitor its size with *sys.getsizeof*.  Another tool for tracking down leaks is to pretty print *gc.garbage*.