# How do I fix this memory leak in pygame?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pygame, pygame-surface

This code snippet is based on the code in the Pygame Cheat Sheet ([here](http://inventwithpython.com/pygamecheatsheet.png)).

```
wht_pix = pygame.Color(0xff,0xff,0xff)
blu_pix = pygame.Color(0x00,0x00,0xff)

pixArr = pygame.PixelArray(self.surface)
for y in xrange(0,self.hgt):
    for x in xrange(0,self.wid):
        if self.grid[x][y]==1: 
            pixArr[x][y] = blu_pix
        else:                  
            pixArr[x][y] = wht_pix
del pixArr  # this line doesn't seem to affect anything

pygame.display.update()
```

I can understand why you'd want to delete pixArr array which is really just a temporary array used as an interface into the pixels of the surface buffer. However, running `top` on my program shows that memory consumption slowly grows. Removing the pixArr block of code eliminates the memory problem, so it's definitely happening within this block of code. Specifically removing the `del PixArr` line seems to make the program behave in exactly the same way (memory consumption grows), which sort of implies that it isn't really freeing up memory when it IS included.

What's wrong with my assumptions? **How do I fix the memory leak?**

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866940/python-memory-leak  - it's (was?) a bug in `PixelArray`. So unfortunately the answer currently is not to use `PixelArray`.

Comment: That's a horrible answer, but i fear it may be correct.

Comment: Crosspost from that answer: "I'm on Python 3.4.0 and using PyGame 1.9.2a0, and running this doesn't give me the leak."

Comment: Note that `del pixArr` does **not** deallocate `pixArr`. It only removes that reference (which *may* trigger deallocation). In that code it doesn't do anything. If there is a problem in the deallocation is a program in pygame's C code, so you can't do much about it.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, just don't keep creating and deleting the`PixelArray`object in the main application loop (not shown in your example). There's several ways to do that, a simple one is shown below:

```
wht_pix = pygame.Color(0xff,0xff,0xff)
blu_pix = pygame.Color(0x00,0x00,0xff)
pixArr = None

while True:  # main application loop
    if pixArr is not None:
        pixArr = pygame.PixelArray(self.surface)
    for y in xrange(0,self.hgt):
        for x in xrange(0,self.wid):
            if self.grid[x][y]==1:
                pixArr[x][y] = blu_pix
            else:
                pixArr[x][y] = wht_pix

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # process all events

    pygame.display.update()

if pixArr is not None:
    del pixArr
```